# rails_admin handling foreign key failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a Rails4 application that uses rails_admin gem and MySql database.

I have a *User* model which `has_many` *Job*s . Now, in rails_admin dashboard, *User* can be deleted normally, **unless** it has some *Jobs*. In that case foreign key fails because there is no `dependent: :destroy` defined on relation. **This is intended behavior**.

However, instead of getting "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails" error I would like to show a nice message: "User can not be deleted if it has jobs".

Is there an elegant way to achieve this in `rails_admin` without making a custom action?

Comment: You could try with a validation, the tough part is running this validation only for rails admin initiated changed. This would require messing with the params to send a custom param on rails admin user editing and then adding a attr_accessor on the user to match this param. Far from elegant.

Answer (score 2):

You can't custom `rails_admin`'s flash error messages, but you can cause an error and redirect to `users`'s index page instead of raise an exception:

```
has_many :jobs, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }` to your migration, for example:

```
class CreateComment < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.references :post, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }
      t.references :user, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't want to cascade on delete, I just want to show a more user-friendly error message that it can't be deleted

Comment: May not answer OP's question, that delete cascade tip was exactly what I was looking for!